# Изменение элемента массива при нажатии на элемент другого массива

Tags: javascript

Буду краток. Есть массив с чекбоксами, собранный с помощью getElementsByClassName, есть другой массив, состоящий из массивов типа [text,true/false]. Задача менять значение true/false в строке с порядковым номером при нажатии на чекбокс с таким-же порядковым номером. Заранее спасибо. Код ниже:
**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" id="in">
    <button id="add">Добавить</button>
    <hr>
    <div id="out"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var todo = [];
if (localStorage.todo != undefined){
    todo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
    go();
}
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {
    var d = document.getElementById('in').value;
    mass = {};
    mass.todo = d;
    mass.c = false;
    i = todo.length;
    todo[i] = mass;
    console.log(todo);
    go();
    localStorage.setItem('todo',JSON.stringify(todo));
}
function go (){
    list='';
    for (var key in todo){
        if (todo[key].c == false) {
            ch = '<input class="che" type="checkbox" >'
        }
        else {
            ch = '<input class="che" type="checkbox" checked>'
        }
        list += todo[key].todo+ch+'<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = list;
}
```

Comment: "Есть массив с чекбоксами" - где?

Comment: if (todo[key].c == false) {
            ch = '<input class="che" type="checkbox" >'
        }
        else {
            ch = '<input class="che" type="checkbox" checked>'
        }
        list += todo[key].todo+ch+'<br>';

Comment: он выводится при помощи document.getElementsByClassName('che');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно при создании чекбоксов добавлять им аттрибут `data-index` с индексом, а затем например

```
document.getElementById('out').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    someAnotherArray[e.target.dataset.index] = e.target.checked
})
```

Comment: вопрос уже решился примерно таким же методом)